# Commerce Email: HTML Mail not reading template

Tags: commerce, emails

I am attempting to make a custom template for my Commerce Email emails. CE uses Variable Email and HTMLMail. I have put the template (named htmlmail--variable_email--custom_email_order.tpl.php) into the root of my theme folder. Nothing. The test htmlmail template is in the same place and works fine. I have cleared caches on the performance and in PHPMyAdmin, and run cron. Still doesn't work. Is this peculiar to Variable Email or HTMLMail?

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to leave the theme selection entry as Current theme; you must explicitly state that you want to use the theme you are already using. Now everything works.